# Why does my corn appear to have perfect flowers?

Tags: botany

Corn is said to be a synchronously monoecious plant with separate male and female flowers.

I am growing a cross between a Peruvian and heirloom variety which seems to be growing some perfect flowers on both main stems, and suckers. I have googled this and find nothing to suggest this happens.

Is this common? And did a corn ancestor also have perfect flowers?

[image: kernel in tassel]
[image: cob in tassel]